# Can't open files through the network

Tags: libreoffice

Why i can't open a file through the network using libreoffice 4.4
in ubuntu 14.10
unless i copy the files from my Desktop!

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Thanks to @Thomas W.,  it appears that this issue is fixed in 4.4.5.2. Update from the PPA: `ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4`

Appears to be a bug as you can see [here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67527#c15). There is indeed a workaround (at least for the version 4.1, but same might work for other version too) posted in the comment#15 in the above link. To reproduce it:

> For Nautilus users:
>
> Open the .desktop file (such as
> /usr/share/applications/libreoffice4.1-writer.desktop for LO Writer)
> and comment the following line: X-GIO-NoFuse=true
>
> For Dolphin users:
>
> Open the same file, and comment the following line:
> X-KDE-Protocols=file,http,smb,ftp,webdav

Comment: These line `X-GIO-NoFuse=true` doesn't seem to be present in the `.desktop` files any longer (version 4.2.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 here), but the problem remains and therefore can't be fixed by commenting out.

Comment: I updated to LibreOffice 4.4.5.2 from `ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4`, and now I can open files from ftp shares alright.

Comment: @Thomas W. Thanks for the information. Updated my answer.

Comment: Another thing I found: When I try to save to FTP, LibreOffice might have to prompt for a password. When canceling this dialog, Writer locks the document as if it was read-only. To work around this, I do a "File => Close", cancel this prompt as well, and the document becomes editable again.

Comment: Problem seems to have returned for LibreOffice 5.1.3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.  The `X-GIO-NoFuse` and `X-KDE-Protocols` are there again, but after commenting them out I get the message "Read-Error. Data could not be read from the file."

Comment: 11 months after Thomas W. 's comment still no solution ?
I have this problem with LO 5.1.3.2 on Xubuntu 17.04...
Here commenting out X-KDE-Protocols does nothing, commenting X-GIO-NoFuse throws an error lie "General in/out error accessing /run/user/1002/gvfs/smb-share:server ..."

Comment: Correction. This LO version is at 5.3.1.2 (to slow for editing my comment)

Comment: Using an sftp connection on thunar, when I run this from command line: "libreoffice --writer /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp\:host\=website.com\,user\=user/home/user/file name.odt" I get ---   General input/output error while accessing /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=website.com,user=user/home/user/file name.odt.