# Xubuntu Libre Office Calc can not open network file

Tags: networking, libreoffice

I have newly installed Xubuntu desktop on a computer. I need to work with files on a NAS store (using samba shares). Libre Office can not open them.

- I browse the network in Thunar and see all files. The are recognised as Open Office files (right icon).
- I can copy files to my desktop.
- I can open the files with gedit.
- On double click I see the Libre Office5 splash sceen then then nothing happens. I do not get any error message.
- When I open Libre Office I can browse to the file with the open dialog but after file selection, I am just back to the blank file.
- I can edit the file after copying it to my desktop.
- After uncommemting `X-GIO-NoFuse=true` in the config file I do get an error when trying to open the file:

  > General input/output error while accessing run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=, share=".
- I have read about a bug to disable `/use/share/applications/libroffice-calc.desktop` and comment out x-KDE prototocls, but that did not help. The question is [Can't open files through the network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634472/cant-open-files-through-the-network).

I did not try to mount the network share with fstab, since I need to be able to work with temporary shares in the file manager.

Anyone else having that problem? How can I solve that?

Using Xubunutu 16.04, amd64, kernel 4.4.0.-64-generic.

Comment: The bug mentioned in the answer you linked was supposedly solved long time ago. Do you have write permissions in the share?

Comment: Indeed I saw the bug was for version 4 and I am using version5. I do have write permissions. Using gedit works fine on the same file. It seems to be just Libre Office. Do you have a network share to test if you can open a file on that with your current installation?

Comment: Works fine (add to test it). It was a very small, half-page long, 22kb odt but size shouldn't matter.

Comment: @CelticWarrior That's an important feedback, so it does not seem a general problem. Just to be sure: You were not using the command line. you used a file manager and connected a network share. You did not use a network share that was already connected via fstab file or such, right? Then you double clicked on a libre office file (size does not matter) and Libre Office did open that file on the network for edition on you local desktop?

Comment: Exactly as you described.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thank you. That means I need to find out what makes Libre Office behave differently in my setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error remains when I use the file managers network browsing function to access an open office file on a share. I still have no idea why it works with gedit and not with open office.

```
General input/output error while accessing
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share..."**
```

Since the question should not remain open indefinitely, I would like to put down the workaround that I found. With that also open office works fine.

The problem goes away when a share is not linked via gvfs as the file manager does it, but with cifs in /etc/fstab. The new entry maps the share to the home folder and uses a credentials file in the home folder

Here is how to do it, detailed explanations are in [[How to select a file from a network share with file manager file open dialog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894053/how-to-select-a-file-from-a-network-share-with-file-manager-file-open-dialog]).

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
nano ~/.smbcredentials
  username=joe
  password=Doe711
  domain=myworkgroupname
chmod 400 ~/.smbcredentials
mkdir ~./network
mkdir ~./network/myserver
mkdir ~./network/myserver/sharename
sudo edit nano /etc/fstab
  //myserver/sharename /home/joe/network/myserver/sharename cifs credentials=/home/joe/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm, 0 0
sudo mount -a
```

Answer (score 5):

"I had a similar problem on Ubuntu. Make sure the Libreoffice Gnome integration package is installed. In my case the package was libreoffice-gnome"

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/9549/unable-to-open-files-from-windows-share/?sort=votes#sort-top

Comment: Wow, it worked! It was so simple.. I removed this package because looked useless in XFCE, but instead is still important for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I had, and was able to solve, the same issue in Xubuntu. LibreOffice could not open the Samba share and showed:

> general I/O error

Lubuntu on the same machine works fine.

My solution was to **install PCmanFM and use it instead of Thunar**.

Now I can dynamically open the share and libreoffice works like a dream. I hope I can help somebody with this tip.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had been trying Thunar and Nemo which both showed the given behaviour. I'll havea look a PCmanFM, but I'd rather stick to nemo. Maybe your input helps to understand the reason of that behaviour..

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I found...

- Working: Opening the same file in /run/user/... as view only with the --view option.
- Working: Opening the same file smb://server/path/...
- Working: Other fuse type mounts(Not things in /run/user/), I tried cryfs, I presume cifs works too.
- Working: Every other program can read/write on  /run/user/...
- Not working: Opening the same file in /run/user/...
- Not working: Opening the same file in /run/user/... with  --nolockcheck
- Not working: Tried opening other types of files(.txt, .xlsx) in /run/user/...

So it only happens on the /run/user/ mount and libreoffice in non-view mode.

I am using pcmanfm which seems to open everything in file///run/user/... instead of smb://...
nautilus uses smb://.. to open files so that works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here with Linux Mint 18 (upgraded from 17.3) Cinnamon since I got version 5.4.3 of LibreOffice.
I used to have a similar issue with previous versions of LibreOffice but there was a know workaround, which was to edit the libreoffice*.desktop files in /usr/share/applications and comment the line *X-GIO-NoFuse=true*.
But since that last upgrade of LO it did not work any more.

However a few details and how I found a solution :

- I use Cinnamon, so that means the file explorer is Nemo (version 3.0.6)
- When opening a file over a samba share, the error only happened with LO Writer not with the other modules such as LO Calc !
- Copying the file to the local hard disk, LO opened it smoothly.
- When opening files using the command line, the error always happened, whether the module is LO Writer or another (LO Calc) !

I eventually noticed something : 
 - that in /usr/share/applications, I now had two sets of libreoffice*.desktop files : one that followed the name syntax *libreoffice-.desktop* and one that followed the syntax *libreoffice5.4-.desktop* (and that actually were symlinks to files in opt/libreoffice5.4/share/xdg ).
 - I also noticed that when doing a right-click on the files, the top choice was 'Open with LibreOffice Writer' but that in the sub-menu 'Open with' there was 'LibreOffice 5.4' and that choosing this, it worked fine !

So I simply replaced the default software choice with 'LibreOffice 5.4' and I am now sorted out.
Still it seems my installation is messy with components left from previous LO versions.