# Can't open libreoffice file on samba server -> session opened for user root by (uid=1000)

Tags: 20.04, samba, libreoffice

There is a samba share in our network and I want to use it from my ubuntu 20.04 To do it I use nautilus -> other locations... When I try to open odt file in gnome (double click) I get `pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)` and file is not opened.

Could anyone say how to fix it?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 and there are at least 2 versions of Ubuntu that could be called 20. What version is it?

Comment: @David I edited the question.

Comment: Maybe you want to check if your problem is similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/894041/xubuntu-libre-office-calc-can-not-open-network-file/1364344#1364344